# Range loop with more variables

Tags: for-loop, go

**SHORT QUESTION:**

Is there a way of doing something like this?

```
for i := 0; key, value := range something; i++ {
    ...
}
```

Or do I have to do it like this?

```
i := 0

for key, value := range something {
    ...
    i++
}
```

---

**EDITED: QUESTION REAL WORLD REASON:**

```
func parseData(xlFile *xlsx.File, parsed [][]string) [][]string {
    i := 0

    for _, sheet := range xlFile.Sheets {
        for _, row := range sheet.Rows {
            parsed = append(parsed, []string{})

            for _, cell := range row.Cells {
                parsed[i] = append(parsed[i], cell.String())
            }

            i++
        }
    }

    return parsed
}
```

Could I inline the `i` declaration in the third `for`?

Comment: I don't think you can combine the three-part `for` style with the one-part `for ... range`. You can have multiple variables in a three-part `for` however.

Comment: The latter. What would the former even mean?

Comment: @Flimzy, i'm using a third party lib to read a xlsx file, and the docs of the library suggest using the for...range, but i need to build a two dimension slice to return it to the api. I'm using the `i` in the latter example to append to the slice in the right position. By the way, that's not the first time i stumble with this, but i don't remember the last one.

Comment: If you're appending to a slice, you don't need an index.

Comment: @Adrian, i think i do. I'll edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: You definitely don't. `append` does not take an index parameter.

Comment: So, how the edited question code is compiling?

Comment: You're not passing the index to `append`, you're indexing into the slice you just appended to, which means that the index will *always* be `len(parsed)-1` (the last item appended to `parsed`). Or you could eliminate the need altogether by looping over `row.Cells` *first* to build your `[]string` in a local var, then appending the completed row to `parsed`.

Comment: @Adrian, i can't iterate over the cells first because the the row in `row.Cells` is generated iterating over the rows. The spreadsheet can have thousands of lines and tens of thousands of cells; so i don't think it's a good ideia to count the rows tens of thousands of times.

Comment: You're already iterating over the cells. I'm saying iterate over them before appending to `parsed`. Then you can get rid of `i`.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/reT30V18VXC - no more iterating than you're doing now. Just simpler and eliminates your problem by using a more sensible order of operations.

Comment: @Adrian, good one.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare `var i` in right place

```
func parseData(xlFile *xlsx.File, parsed [][]string) [][]string {

    for _, sheet := range xlFile.Sheets {
        for i, row := range sheet.Rows {
            parsed = append(parsed, []string{})

            for _, cell := range row.Cells {
                parsed[i] = append(parsed[i], cell.String())
            }
        }
    }

    return parsed
}
```

You can play here https://play.golang.org/p/3XXTuwoUsFw

Comment: That's a good one. I'll prefer that implementation until someone give a definitive answer. Voted up.